# Include Django Project specific objects in Django package

Tags: python, django, python-module

I'm developing a web-app with common components and decided to pack those common components (some views, templates, logic) in a Django package.

Now the problem is: I want to access variables of my specific Django project, depending on the project, from the package. In this specific instance:

My Django package has an admin panel. A custom-made admin panel that allows me to manage a list of algorithms. However, these algorithms change. In one specific Django project I might have 3 algorithms, in another one I might have 5.

The admin panel in the Django package allows me to edit custom algorithm components, such as weights, test cases, etc.

Now my problem is, in the Django view, in the package, I want to access the Django project's algorithms in order to show them. As a list, for selection/editing/deleting, but also to view them in detail and edit them.

Now my problem is, obviously, I can't include something from the Django project in the Django package, otherwise it would become a dependency. And the algorithms are different and unique in each specific project.

So, in short, the question is how to access specific data of a Django project by a package used by that project, without making the package dependent of anything.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after some more investigation I found a possible solution for this. Will leave it here for informational purposes while waiting for an answer.

Instead of loading the package URLs as a module I use a custom function that passes the Django project's variables to the package URLs, and therefore, the views.

So in the project urls.py, instead of:

```
url(r'^package/$', include('package.urls'))
```

I use

```
url(r'^package/$', obtain_package_urls(custom_content))
```

where obtain_package_urls() is a function in the package:

```
def obtain_package_urls(custom_content):
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^url1$', view1, {'custom_content': custom_content},
        url(r'^url2$', view2, {'custom_content': custom_content},
    )
    return (urlpatterns, None, None)
```

The goal is to, instead of the include function that includes the static URL-view mapping of Django, to use this function that returns a dynamic URL-view mapping with the custom content included in the views.

So in effective terms with the algorithms I ended up doing:

```
#Django project settings.py
obtain_algorithm_list():
    return Algorithm.objects.all()

#Django project urls.py
from project.settings import obtain_algorithm_list

urlpatterns = ...
    ...
    url(r'^package/$', obtain_package_urls(obtain_algorithm_list())
    ...

#In the package urls.py
urlpatterns = ...
    url(r'^view1/$', view1, {'algorithms': algorithms},
    ...

#And then in each package view
def view(request, algorithms=[]):
    ...
    use_for_something(algorithms)
```